# Implementing matching in database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, django

I am working on a project where people choose certain slots everyday. Then I match people who are in the same slot with each other. I am using a separate table for implementing this. The design that I am using currently is

```
user_id (FK to user table)
created
updated
slotno (int)
```

Equivalent django models

```
class Slots(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_id')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slotno = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

The problem is

1. The table will become extremely large over time, leading to
   increasing complexity of sql queries (one possible solution can be
   to set up a job that checks the timestamp of all the rows and
   deletes the rows which are more than 24 hours old)
2. When I'll query the database for all the users who are in the same
   slot then all the users who were in that slot any time
   in the past will also show up (MAJOR FLAW)

This design is definitely flawed but I am not able to come up with a good design to implement the feature. I am a noob to database design and this is the first time I have to implement a non-trivial database design.

**PS**: I am using django 1.6.5 with mysql.

Comment: How large is extremely large? MySQL supports partitioning on date ranges, which can make for extremely efficient queries even on hundreds of millions of rows. Or, you could always archive off the data every day, week, month, depending on your usage. Could you give some examples of expected use cases/queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your query look like?

If you only want people whose database entry was created today, you could do something like

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
today = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day)
```

And then you could filter based on this, e.g.

```
your_query.filter(created__gte = today)
```

As for the size of the database - If this is really going to be a problem for you, you could implement an archival system. Maybe a cron job that runs once a day and writes old entries to a .csv file or a separate database or something.